# XPath Query: get attribute href from a tag

Tags: html, xpath, domdocument

I want to use XPath to get the `href` attribute from an `a`-tag, but it has two occurrences within the same file. How am I getting along?
I need to check IF there is an `href` attribute with value $street/object, I have got this code and it does not work:

```
$product_photo     = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@href,'{$object_street}fotos/')][1]");
        $product_360       = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@href,'{$object_street}360-fotos/')][1]");
        $product_blueprint = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@href,'{$object_street}plattegrond/')][1]");
        $product_video     = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@href,'{$object_street}video/')][1]");
```

It does not return anything at all. Who can help me out?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

For the following HTML document:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a> 
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">SO</a> 
  </body>
</html>
```

The xpath query `/html/body//a/@href` (or simply `//a/@href`) will return:

```
    http://www.example.com
    http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

To select a specific instance use `/html/body//a[N]/@href`,

```
    $ /html/body//a[2]/@href
    http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

To test for strings contained in the attribute and return the attribute itself place the check on the tag not on the attribute:

```
    $ /html/body//a[contains(@href,'example')]/@href
    http://www.example.com
```

Mixing the two:

```
    $ /html/body//a[contains(@href,'com')][2]/@href
    http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: **EDIT:** How could I check for a specific href attribute? Shall I then use `/html/body//a[1]/@href='{$object_street}/x'`?

Comment: Thank you a lot for the effort! Unfortunately, I am still having trouble, I suppose it is not the query that is wrong. Do you mind taking a look at the procedural code for me and putting me on the right track?

Because, if so, I will post the code.

Comment: Make sure your query evaluates the {$object_street} properly, maybe put it in a string first, as in "string s = //a[contains(@href,'{$object_street}fotos/')][1]/@href" and check that `s` looks allright.

Comment: I have put my question here, but nobody is responding to it. So maybe you could take a look at it, please?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry for not including the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406694/domdocument-and-xpath-no-url-passed?noredirect=1#comment32292479_21406694

Comment: Apologies, I am not well versed enough in php to comment on your problem. The question looks too long to me though, maybe you could distill it to a small sample html (as in my example) and the essence of php code that fails? It will make easier on SO users to read and answer.

Comment: The problem is that I am not sure about where the code fails, whether it is about a conditional, or the XPath query or something else, haha. So I find it hard to distill it.

Comment: It is returning an array not the specific string value

Comment: for some reason i don't get the url back I get `<link href="http://example.com" />` instead of `<link>{$link}</link>`

Answer (score 7):

The answer shared by @mockinterface is correct. Although I would like to add my 2 cents to it.

If someone is using frameworks like `scrapy` the you will have to use `/html/body//a[contains(@href,'com')][2]/@href` along with get() like this:

```
response.xpath('//a[contains(@href,'com')][2]/@href').get()
```