# How to get xpath for url with a text beside?

Tags: php, html, xpath

I have below example. I want to extract  url from below using xpath. The url keeps changing but the text "Url" and div class is same throughout. Is it possible to extract url from just the text "Url" and the text Url is outside `<a>`

```
<div class="Dataset">
"data1 : value1"
<br>
"data2: value2"
<br>
    "Url :"
    <a href="http://somechangingurl.com"/>
<br>
"data3: value3"
<br>
"data4: value4"
</div>
```

Comment: you can use regex to get a result.

Comment: Piece of cake to find on the net.. here is a good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455349/xpath-query-get-attribute-href-from-a-tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. Below is what i did.

```
//div[@class="Dataset"]/text()[contains(.,'Url :')]/following-sibling::a/@href
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I think that xpath is a good way to go to get the URL, since you want the preceding text, I would go for a regex:

```
$re = '/"(.+)"\s+<a href="(.+)"/';
$str = '<div class="Dataset">
"data1 : value1"
<br>
"data2: value2"
<br>
    "Url :"
    <a href="http://somechangingurl.com"/>
<br>
"data3: value3"
<br>
"data4: value4"
</div>';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```