# How do I get the text element of a hyperlink from a web page using Python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

I am scraping web data and need to return just the text element associated with a hyperlink. The hyperlink and text are unknown. The class is known. Here is example HTML:

```
<div class="a-column SsCol" role = "gridcell">
    <h3 class="a-spacing-none SsName">
        <span class="a-size-medium a-text-bold">
            <a href="/gp/aag/main/ref=sm_name_2?ie=UTF8&ids=15112acd">Direct Name</a>
        </span>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Alternatively, the desired text may be associated with an image instead of a hyperlink:

```
<div class="a-column SsCol" role = "gridcell">
    <h3 class="a-spacing-none SsName">
            <img alt="Direct Name" src="https://images-hosted.com//01x-j.gi">
    </h3>
</div>
```

I have tried the method below:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
response = requests.get('https://www.exampleurl.com/')
doc = html.fromstring(response.content)
text1 = doc.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'SsName')]/text()")
```

I am using lxml instead of BeautifulSoup, but am willing to switch if it is recommended.
The desired result is:

```
print(text1)
['Direct Name']
```

Comment: When associated with img will it always be the value of the alt attribute for the text you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//*[contains(@alt, '')]/@alt` find all tags which have alt element. In reality, this xpath is extended from [XPath Query: get attribute href from a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455349/xpath-query-get-attribute-href-from-a-tag). And you can select specific tag, as my `text2` showed

```
from lxml import html

text = """
<div class="a-column SsCol" role = "gridcell">
    <h3 class="a-spacing-none SsName">
        <span class="a-size-medium a-text-bold">
            <a href="/gp/aag/main/ref=sm_name_2?ie=UTF8&ids=15112acd">Direct Name</a>
        </span>
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="a-column SsCol2" role = "gridcell">
    <h3 class="a-spacing-none SsName">
            <img alt="Direct Name" src="https://images-hosted.com//01x-j.gi">
    </h3>
</div>

"""

doc = html.fromstring(text)
text1 = doc.xpath("//*[contains(@alt, '')]/@alt")
print(text1)
text2 = doc.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'a-column SsCol2')]//*[contains(@alt, '')]/@alt")
print(text2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely give Beautiful Soup a try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
```

Some common ways to navigate over the structure

```
soup.title
# <title>The Dormouse's story</title>

soup.title.name
# u'title'

soup.title.string
# u'The Dormouse's story'

soup.title.parent.name
# u'head'

soup.p
# <p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

soup.p['class']
# u'title'

soup.a
# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>

soup.find_all('a')
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>]

soup.find(id="link3")
# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>
```

One common task is extracting all the URLs found within a page’s  tags:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
# http://example.com/elsie
# http://example.com/lacie
```

Another common task is extracting all the text from a page:

```
print(soup.get_text())
# The Dormouse's story
#
# The Dormouse's story
#
# Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
# Elsie,
# Lacie and...
```

If you need anything else you might wanna check their documentation:
[Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)